# SQL: How to count distinct for all hourly periods in a day

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table of hotel data like this:

| Room_ID | Check_in_time | Check_out_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-10-01 01:02:03 | 2021-10-01 02:03:04 |

I would like to do a count of how many rooms were were checked in during each hour throughout a day (even if the room was checked in for 1 minute during the hour it still counts), so an output that look like this:

| Time period | Number of rooms |
| --- | --- |
| 09:00-10:00 | 10 |
| 10:00-11:00 | 12 |
| .. | .. |

There are a couple of other 'where' conditions but this is the crux of the problem. I have so far managed to write a query that can count unique room ID by specifying the hourly window:

```
select count (distinct room_id)
from data
where check_out_time > 9am and check_in_time < 10am
```

But how do I do this for each of the 24 hourly windows without repeating the same query 24 times? Hopefully something that can be later adapted into half hour intervals, or even minutes. I'm using Sigma in case that matters. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Outer join a help table storing the values 0 - 23. GROUP BY.

Comment: Hello @korgro, please tell us what database do you use ? Is it Oracle ? SQLServer ?

Comment: You mentioned that you are using Sigma in your question. Are you referring to this [tool](https://help.sigmacomputing.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037430513-SQL-Runner)? If so what type of database does your sql connection use? Sharing the type of database will allow other stackoverflow users to provide answers that specifically address your question especially when your question includes datetime data which has different functions in different types of databases

Comment: @ggordon the data is stored on Snowflake - I'm assuming that's what you guys refer to as SQL server / connection? And yep that's the tool I use.

Comment: @VBoka the data is stored on Snowflake - I'm assuming that's what you guys refer to as SQL server / connection?

Answer (score 2):

In Snowflake, I'd leverage a `DATE_TRUNC` function.  If your dataset is very large, this will likely perform much better than any of the `BETWEEN` type of filtering that the OP and other answers are using.

```
select date_trunc('hour',check_out_time) as check_out_hour
     , count (distinct room_id) as cnt
from data
group by 1;
```

If you needed to parse it out by day and time, you could add that, as well:

```
select date_trunc('day',check_out_time) as check_out_day
     , date_trunc('hour',check_out_time) as check_out_hour
     , count (distinct room_id) as cnt
from data
group by 1,2;
```

For reference:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

A recursive CTE is used to generate the possible hours 0-23 (we could have also select distinct hours from your existing dataset but i did not want to assume that every hour was possibly booked and this may be a less expensive operation for this case to get all possible hours). A left join was then used to determine hours rooms were booked before aggregating this and counting the number of bookings each hour.

```sql
WITH recursive hours(hr) as (
    select 0 as hr 
    union all
    select hr + 1 from hours where hr < 23
)
select 
    concat(h.hr,':00-',(h.hr+1),':00') as time_period,
    COUNT(DISTINCT r.room_id) as no_rooms
from hours h
left join room_times r on (
                           CAST(r.check_in_time AS DATE) = CAST(r.check_out_time AS DATE) AND
                           h.hr BETWEEN DATE_PART(hour,r.Check_in_time)  AND  DATE_PART(hour,r.Check_out_time)
                          ) OR
                          (
                           CAST(r.check_in_time AS DATE) < CAST(r.check_out_time AS DATE) AND  
                           (
                               h.hr >= DATE_PART(hour, r.Check_in_time) OR 
                               h.hr <= DATE_PART(hour,r.Check_out_time)
                           )
                          
                          )

                         
GROUP BY h.hr
order by h.hr
```

See working db fiddle (using sql server instead) with the same logic and additional data and outputs to assist verification [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=f2b01f0835ec95cbdea070d4401f05d3).

Sample Data:

```sql
INSERT INTO room_times
  (Room_ID, Check_in_time, Check_out_time)
VALUES
  ('123', '2021-10-01 01:02:03', '2021-10-01 03:03:04'),
  ('124', '2021-10-01 15:02:03', '2021-10-02 01:03:04');
```

Outputs:

| time_period | no_rooms |
| --- | --- |
| 0:00-1:00 | 1 |
| 1:00-2:00 | 2 |
| 2:00-3:00 | 1 |
| 3:00-4:00 | 1 |
| 4:00-5:00 | 0 |
| 5:00-6:00 | 0 |
| 6:00-7:00 | 0 |
| 7:00-8:00 | 0 |
| 8:00-9:00 | 0 |
| 9:00-10:00 | 0 |
| 10:00-11:00 | 0 |
| 11:00-12:00 | 0 |
| 12:00-13:00 | 0 |
| 13:00-14:00 | 0 |
| 14:00-15:00 | 0 |
| 15:00-16:00 | 1 |
| 16:00-17:00 | 1 |
| 17:00-18:00 | 1 |
| 18:00-19:00 | 1 |
| 19:00-20:00 | 1 |
| 20:00-21:00 | 1 |
| 21:00-22:00 | 1 |
| 22:00-23:00 | 1 |
| 23:00-24:00 | 1 |

Let me know if this works for you.